# Deserializing to a class using non-constructor method

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, fasterxml

I am attempting to deserialize a jackson-serialized Google Ads sdk object. In particular, I am running into issues in instantiating specific classes which behave like enums, for example :

```
public class CampaignStatus implements Serializable {
    private String _value_;
    private static HashMap _table_ = new HashMap();
    public static final String _UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN";
    public static final String _ENABLED = "ENABLED";
    public static final String _PAUSED = "PAUSED";
    public static final String _REMOVED = "REMOVED";
    public static final CampaignStatus UNKNOWN = new CampaignStatus("UNKNOWN");
    public static final CampaignStatus ENABLED = new CampaignStatus("ENABLED");
    public static final CampaignStatus PAUSED = new CampaignStatus("PAUSED");
    public static final CampaignStatus REMOVED = new CampaignStatus("REMOVED");
    private static TypeDesc typeDesc = new TypeDesc(CampaignStatus.class);

    protected CampaignStatus(String value) {
        this._value_ = value;
        _table_.put(this._value_, this);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this._value_;
    }

    public static CampaignStatus fromValue(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        CampaignStatus enumeration = (CampaignStatus)_table_.get(value);
        if (enumeration == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return enumeration;
        }
    }

    public static CampaignStatus fromString(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return fromValue(value);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return this.toString().hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this._value_;
    }

    public Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return fromValue(this._value_);
    }

    public static Serializer getSerializer(String mechType, Class _javaType, QName _xmlType) {
        return new EnumSerializer(_javaType, _xmlType);
    }

    public static Deserializer getDeserializer(String mechType, Class _javaType, QName _xmlType) {
        return new EnumDeserializer(_javaType, _xmlType);
    }

    public static TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new QName("https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809", "CampaignStatus"));
    }
}
```

When a Campaign object is serialized (which contains a CampaignStatus as defined above), the JSON looks like this:

"status":{"value":"ENABLED"}

The deserializer throws a mismatched input exception when trying to write a JSON campaign to a Campaign object. Since the objects are owned by Google, I can't modify the existing classes or add annotations. My solution needs to work for 250+ classes that follow this pattern, so individually wrapping or extending these isn't a feasible solution. Additionally, I will have many different stakeholders serializing these objects, so modifying how they are serialized is also not a useable solution.

What I need is some way to indicate to the deserializer that when it comes across a situation like this, it should look for the fromValue method and use that. I'm ok with explicitly stating what json keys/values would need to use such a method; I just need a more dynamic way of modifying the serialization than extending the class or adding annotations.

Comment: _"Since the objects are owned by Google, I can't modify the existing classes or add annotations."_ Jackson supports [mixin annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) that let you apply annotations to code that you don't control. But I guess since you're working with so many classes, that would be just as much work as wrapping or extending them all, which you've stated you'd rather not do.

Comment: That's definitely useful to note. If this isn't doable in a generic manner, then using those mixin annotations would probably be more realistic than extending each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate factory method using `@JsonCreator` annotation - it is going to be used by Jackson to perform deserialization.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
    @JsonCreator
    public static CampaignStatus fromValue(@JsonProperty("value") String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        CampaignStatus enumeration = (CampaignStatus)_table_.get(value);
        if (enumeration == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            return enumeration;
        }
    }
```

I am a bit confused with what exactly you are trying to achieve but feel free to put any logic that fulfill you requirements in the method above.

Comment: I've seen this solution in my research and it could definitely work, the problem is this isn't feasible because 1. I can't modify those files unless I fork the whole Google Ads library 2. I need to do this for a significant quantity of classes.

The solution I'm looking for is a way of deserializing these without explicitly modifying/extending the existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find the best possible solution, but I'll share the best I could come up with. I implemented a new generic deserializer extending JsonDeserializer, and used reflection in the deserialize method to invoke the .fromValue method. I then used reflection to search the directories for all classes, and search each class for a matching .fromValue method. Every time I successfully find a class that follows this pattern, I register it with the mapper using a new generic deserializer for the corresponding class. It's a bit costly, but I only register the deserializers at instantiation so it's ok that it's a complex.